# How to include SQLite JDBC driver to docker image?

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

I try to create a docker image of an servlet app which uses SQLite database or xml for storing data and tomcat to set the app up. It is defined in the environment variable which type of storage the app uses. When I use xml everything is alright, but when I try to switch to db the app doesn't see the JDBC driver i provided. I tried using different methods to provide it, I've added it to WEB-INF/lib directory before creating WAR file, I tried to copy it to /usr/local/tomcat/lib directory in the Dockerfile, I tried to mount it as a volume, nothing works. I still get the same error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:/build/library.db
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
at library.LibrarySQLDAO.<init>(LibrarySQLDAO.java:103)
at library.AuthorServlet.doGet(AuthorServlet.java:216)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:501)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM tomcat:9.0-alpine
COPY LibraryWeb.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
COPY library.db build/library.db
COPY library.xml build/library.xml
COPY sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.3.jar /usr/local/tomcat/lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.3.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENV XML_FILE_LOCATION=build/library.xml
ENV SQLITE_FILE_LOCATION=build/library.db
ENV STORAGE_ENGINE=sql
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

Right now I'm out of ideas what could I've done wrong, please give me a hint. I'm new to Java and Docker too. I also know that containing data storage in the container isn't a good idea, but for now I want to make it just work, then I'll think how to provide data storage correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. extract libsqlitejdbc.so from sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.3.jar
2. copy libsqlitejdbc.so to /usr/lib

example:

```
RUN unzip -j sqlite-jdbc-*.jar "org/sqlite/native/$(uname -s)/$(uname -m)/libsqlitejdbc.so"
RUN mv libsqlitejdbc.so /usr/lib
```